# Facet error "path_not_indexed" in Clusterpoint Cloud

Tags: clusterpoint, database, nosql

Could not implement faceted search. I need to categorize and count “office” values.

I post data with REST:

```
{"query":"*","docs":"0","offset":"0","facet":"company.employee.office"}
```

but get an error:

```
"problem_terms":{"path_not_indexed":"company.employee.office\/facet"}
```

I have indexed “//document/company/employee” as index=xml&text&facet.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The are two things you need to correct in your request:

- you should define child tags starting from the last parent tag that has index=xml rule. You have indexed “employee” as xml, so “company” is needless
- you have to change syntax for path definition from “.” to “/”

The correct request could look like:

```
{"query":"*","docs":"0","offset":"0","facet":"employee/office"}
```